# Creating Custom Layout in ASP.Net MVC3 using Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

Hello In my project i have to implement a new layout page from an existing Html file.How to implement it?i know how to do it in Asp.net master page..But that way is not working here ..Here am attaching my Logic.Then you can understand what am expecting..
[image: Site sample]

I have all the html and css code for the same.
I want to know where to start and How?

**My Layout Top Bar Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-alpona.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/prettify.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/responsive-tables.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles.css.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-reset.css.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="scroll-top">
                <a href="#" class="tip-top" title="Go Top"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- TOP BAR -->
            <div class="top-bar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" class="left-toggle"><i class="icon-menu-2 "></i></a>
                            <!-- LOGO -->
                            <div class="branding">
                                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/alpona-logo.png" alt="Alpona Logo"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 responsive-notification-mnu">
                            <ul class="notification-bar">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-bell"></i></a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <div class="dropdown-head">
                                            <h6>You have 10 new notifications</h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="notification-list">
                                            <li><a href="#" class="clearfix"><i class="icon-star blue"></i><span class="notification-intro">Donec pretium enim vel nisl viverra posuere.<span class="notification-time">8 min ago</span></span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="clearfix"><i class=" icon-bell orange"></i><span class="notification-intro">Vestibulum viverra magna vitae dui volutpat dapibus. <span class="notification-time">3 hours ago</span></span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="clearfix"><i class=" icon-bolt brown"></i><span class="notification-intro">Fusce eget ipsum in odio consectetur condimentum et id nisl.<span class="notification-time">5 hours ago</span></span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="clearfix"><i class=" icon-ok-sign green"></i><span class="notification-intro">Mauris fringilla metus in mauris molestie tempor <span class="notification-time">8 hours ago</span></span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="action-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-block">View All</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="count-noty">12</span><i class="icon-envelop-opened"></i></a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <div class="dropdown-head">
                                            <h6>You have 32 new messages</h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="msg-list">
                                            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="dropdown-thumb"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Avatar" src="images/avatar-40x40/binjal.png"></span><span><i>binjal</i> is posted an article. lacus est congue... </span><span class="notification-meta"> 12 hours ago </span></a></li>
                                            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="dropdown-thumb"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Avatar" src="images/avatar-40x40/sharmin.png"></span><span><i>sharmin</i> is posted an article. lacus est congue... </span><span class="notification-meta"> 12 hours ago </span></a></li>
                                            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="dropdown-thumb"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Avatar" src="images/avatar-40x40/shusi.png"></span><span><i>shusi</i> is posted an article. lacus est congue... </span><span class="notification-meta"> 12 hours ago </span></a></li>
                                            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="dropdown-thumb"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Avatar" src="images/avatar-40x40/jamjam.png"></span><span><i>jamjam</i> is posted an article. lacus est congue... </span><span class="notification-meta"> 12 hours ago </span></a></li>
                                            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="dropdown-thumb"><img width="40" height="40" alt="Avatar" src="images/avatar-40x40/sinha.png"></span><span><i>sinha</i> is posted an article. lacus est congue... </span><span class="notification-meta"> 12 hours ago </span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="action-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-block">View All</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 clearfix responsive-log-mnu">
                            <!-- ADMIN DRODOWN MENU -->
                            <div class="loged-nav pull-right">
                                <ul class="clearfix">
                                    <li class="log-nav dropdown pull-right"><a class="dropdown-toggle clearfix" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <span class="pull-left loged-user-name">Sharmin Sultana</span><span class="logged-user-thumb pull-right"><img class="img-circle" src="images/admin-avatar.jpg" alt="Admin"></span></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <ul class="pull-right">
                                                <li><a href="#">kjamanebr@gmail.com</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" class="logout-link"><i class="icon-lock-3"></i> Logout</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- LEFT BAR -->
            <div class="left-bar merge-left">
                <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- LEFT NAV -->
                <div class="left-nav">
                    <ul class="side-navigation accordion" id="nav-accordion">
                        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i>Forms</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="form-elements.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>All Form Elements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="extended-form-elements.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Extended Form Elements <span class="nav-instruction"> Lots of plugins is used here</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="form-validation.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>Form Validation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="form-wizard.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>Stepy Form</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-table-2"></i>Tables</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="basic-table.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Basic Tables <span class="nav-instruction"> This is an instruction</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="table-themes.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Tables-Theme</a></li>
                                <li><a href="data-tables.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Data Tables</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-columns"></i> Grid/Portlets</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="boxy-grids-porlets.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Boxy Grid/Portlets <span class="nav-instruction"> This is an instruction</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="non-boxy-grids-porlets.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Non Boxy Grid/Portlets</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-laptop"></i> Layout &AMP; Dashboard</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="blank-layout.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Blank Layout <span class="nav-instruction"> This is an instruction</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="fixed-topbar.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Fixed Topbar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="fixed-leftbar.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Fixed Leftbar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="top-dropdown-menu.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Top Dropdown Menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="no-sidebar.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> No Sidebar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-font"></i> Typography</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="typography-boxy.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Boxy Typography <span class="nav-instruction"> This is an instruction</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="typography-non-boxy.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Non Boxy Typography</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cord"></i> UI Elements</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="bootstrap-ui.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Bootstrap UI <span class="nav-instruction"> This is an instruction</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="jquery-ui.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> jQuery UI</a></li>
                                <li><a href="extended-ui-elements.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Extended Elements<span class="nav-instruction"> More Cool UI elements plugins </span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tools"></i> Components &AMP; Plugins</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="buttons-icons.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Buttons &AMP; Icons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="wysiwyg.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> WYSIWYG Text Editor</a></li>
                                <li><a href="calendar.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Calendar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="flot-chart.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Flot Chart</a></li>
                                <li><a href="google-chart.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Google Chart</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-files"></i> Example Pages</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="content-post.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Content Post</a></li>
                                <li><a href="login.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="product-list.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Products List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gallery.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Gallery Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="search-page.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Search Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="error-page.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Error Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="invoice-page.html"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> Invoice</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <div>

            @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [MVC3 Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-10)!

The last part of that tutorial describes how design the layout to include partial views using the Html.RenderAction() method. Also see the Html.RenderSection() method.

the basic concept is:

```
<body>
    <div id=maincontainer>
        <div id=topsection>
            <div class=topbar>
                Top Bar              
            </div>            
            <div class="nav">
                <ul><li>Home</li></ul>
            </div>            
        </div>
<div id="sidebar">
          <b>Side bar</b>
    </div>
    <div id=contentwrapper>
        <div id=contentcolumn>
            <div class=body>                    
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id=footer>Footer</div>

</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new _layout page and pasting your HTML into it! ensuring the CSS links are referenced correctly? Apart from the syntax changes @ instead of <% %>, the only real difference is that you define sections instead of placeholders.

Can you post some example code so we can see where your issue lies?

Comment: Hello I have updated the Question with Code

Comment: What you've posted looks ok, but I'd suggest you look into bundling your included script and style files (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification). I'd also put the menus into partial views and include them into the _layout page.

Comment: Hello Chris W here my page is running without Styles and scripts.So by using bundling can i rectify the problem